# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object when using NLTK word_tokenize

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file and then using NLTK to analyse the text.  The CSV file contain several columns but now I only want to analyse one column in this file so far.

The sample of csv file is:
[sample data from csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjScL.png)

The code for read CSV file and using the word_tokenize are below:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
#nltk.download('all')

data=pd.read_csv("Output-analysis.csv")
print (data.SAT_COMMENTS)

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenize_word=word_tokenize(data.SAT_COMMENTS)
print(tokenize_word)
```

It seems I can read and print the SAT_Comment column no problem, but when I try to use word_tokenize, it is pointing there are some lines in csv file and then TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object error.

error details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\Desktop\SAT analysis\Attempts.py", line 22, in <module>
    tokenize_word=word_tokenize(data.SAT_COMMENTS)
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 129, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 107, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1272, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1326, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1326, in <listcomp>
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1316, in span_tokenize
    for sl in slices:
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1357, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 314, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Users\Rachel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1330, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any suggestions? I know word_tokenize deal with on record one time not for string, but I can not figure out whats wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no NaNs in that column

```
data.SAT_COMMENTS = data.SAT_COMMENTS.fillna('')
```